# apache2: bad user name www-data

Tags: php, apache-2.2, web-server

- Starting web server apache2                                                                        apache2: bad user name www-data

I just tried restarting my webserver because of an update I did to my php.ini and originally I was getting something about the PID file being overwritten.

Now I just get this:  * Starting web server apache2                                                                        apache2: bad user name www-data

this has NEVER happened before, and I haven't changed and permissions or apache2 configuration files.

What gives?

Comment: What Linux are you on? Does it have an auto-update function? I see quite a lot of forum posts on the net who lost their `www-data` user due to an automatic update of the OS.

Answer (score 2):

1. You may deleted user www-data. Check `id www-data`, output should be like this:

```
# id www-data
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data),2522(psaserv),2523(psacln)
```

If no such user exists, add it: `adduser www-data`

2. You may overwritten your Apache config with config from other computer, where exists user `www-data`. If so, restore old config, or check config and replace user with existent one (for example, `www`).

Answer (score 0):

close all apache connection from the Task Manager first may b this will work
and then restart the services

Comment: From the scarce data there is, this question doesn't look Windows-related (www-data is the default Apache user on UN*X-like systems). Also, it's "maybe".

Answer (score 0):

Look at your /etc/passwd file and retrieve what the name of the apache user is on your system.

Then adjust your config accordingly

If no user in /etc/passwd is available then you should recreate it, as somethings was gone wrong in the update process.